# C++, DirectX 9, Windows API - Resizing changes my coordinates?

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, image-resizing

I draw a rectangle to be 500 x 500 pixels.

My Window is 1920 x 1080.

When I resize the screen to lets say 1376 x 768, the image that was 500 x 500 pixels is now slightly smaller (It has been scaled and squished).. How do I prevent this?

I assume this is where the flags are going to be for that kind of setting but I cannot find the setting I need:

```
ZeroMemory( &presParams, sizeof( presParams ) );
presParams.Windowed = TRUE;
presParams.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
presParams.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_UNKNOWN;
presParams.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_ONE;

d3dObject = Direct3DCreate9( D3D_SDK_VERSION );
hr = d3dObject->CreateDevice(
    D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
    D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
    hWnd, 
    D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, 
    &presParams, 
    &d3dDevice
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative size/shape of the scene was affect by the back buffer size and aspect ration of projection matrix, so you need to reset back buffer size when you re-size your window or change your screen resolution, this will prevent the scene from being stretched.

```
presParams.BackBufferWidth = window_width or screen_width;
presParams.BackBufferHeight = window_height or screen_height;
```

and then, call pd3dDeveice->Reset(presParams) to reset device.

After this, you should reset your projection matrix to make the aspect ratio = window_width / window_height or screen_width / screen_height, for example:

```
D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&proj_matrix, D3DX_PI / 4, ration, 1.0f, 1000.0f);
```

Comment: Ahhh THANK YOU GOOD SIR! So it is DirectX that comes with this auto scaling thing when the backbuffer has been stretched. So cool. I'll try this when i get home!